# Laravel multiple records update with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to `Update` multiple records to the reference table. Here is the response of the `$request`.

```
array:21 [
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "xXukmVEsMvyeBODIURqFx9Mhk4LviYrV6iLmAuOY"
  "account_type" => "0"
  "name" => "test"
  "model_id" => "2"
  "location" => "USA"
  "serial_no" => "00055555"
  "status" => "Sales"
  "capacity_lower" => ""
  "weight" => "1212.000"
  "category" => "1"
  "attribute" => array:3 [
    1 => array:1 [
      1 => "1"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      3 => "5"
      2 => "2"
    ]
    4 => array:5 [
      5 => "11"
      6 => "13"
      4 => "9"
      7 => "23"
      8 => "37"
    ]
  ]
  "crane_manufacture_id" => "1"
  "condition" => "Average"
  "manufacture_year" => "2020"
  "unit_no" => "222222"
  "hours" => "100"
  "video_url" => ""
  "sub_category" => "4"
  "description" => "dsfs"
  "productImages" => array:7 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "id" => "27"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "id" => "28"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "id" => "29"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    3 => array:3 [
      "id" => "30"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    4 => array:3 [
      "id" => "31"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    5 => array:3 [
      "id" => "32"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
    6 => array:3 [
      "id" => "33"
      "descripton" => "89d9a500-a936-4510-9ca5-5952ee9c0bff.jpg"
      "status_id" => "2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I have two tables, Products and product_images.  I have given relation that one product has multiple images. I have apply `hasMany` relationship in both table.

Now at the time of Update record I am follow the below code for updating product_images records.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
        $product = Product::find($id);
        //$product->save($request->input());
        $product->productImages()->update(new ProductImage($request->input('productImages')));
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

But I am facing error with "**MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 452:
0**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your model both products and product_images has fillable property. refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
protected $fillable = ['list of columns to be inserted'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the fillable property `protected $fillable = [];` or use for all properties from the `$request` `protected $guarded = [];`